# How do you split a string into a list of strings all of length 3?

Tags: string, haskell

Stuck on a problem, if I wanted to split a list of characters such as "qwertyzxc" (9 elements) (`['q','w','e','r','t','y','z','x','c']`) into a list of strings with the length 3. How would I do it?
Example:

Input : `['q','w','e','r','t','y','z','x','c']`
Output : `[['q','w','e'],['r','t','y'],['z','x','c']]`

Thanks, I have been stuck on this for quite a while

Comment: What if the list is not dividable by three?

Comment: The input is always going to be of size nine. It's just the way it's utilised. If it's not 9, I guess it will give you an error message saying it's not the correct size.

Comment: Data.List.Split.chunksOf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If segment length is fixed as 3 and then you may do as follows by pattern matching

```
segment :: [a] -> [[a]]
segment []           = []
segment [x]          = [[x]]
segment [x,y]        = [[x,y]]
segment (x:y:z:rest) = [x,y,z] : segment rest

*Main> segment [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: My GHCI returns *Main> ["..3.2.6..","9..3.5..1","..18.64..","..81.29..","7.......8","..67.82..","..26.95..","8..2.3..9","..5.1.3.."]. Do you know why it's using ' " ' instead of ' [ ' ?

Comment: Because a String is a list of Char and the Show instance is defined to show a list of characters as a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
p3::[a] -> [[a]]
p3 [] = []
p3 l = take 3 l : (p3 $ drop 3 l)
```

as you might notice, you can easily turn it to a more general version of `pN`

Comment: I love this solution, so concise using regression and generalising well, too!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also try this, having the checking of the length for free:

```
segment :: [a] -> [[a]]
segment [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i] = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
segment           _         = error "the list hasn't 9 items"
```

then you try:

```
> segment [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

and

```
> segment [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
*** Exception: the list hasn't 9 items
```

Comment: @Zarolan, Strings are list of chars. ghci usually displays the list `'h':'o':'l':'a':[]` as `"hola"`

Answer (score 0):

### Using chunksOf from Data.List.Split

A prepackaged answer is referenced in a comment by [n. 'pronouns' m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-pronouns-m), though the [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.4/docs/Data-List-Split.html) needs to be installed.

```hs
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
chunksOf :: Int -> [e] -> [[e]]
--Sample Usage
chunksOf 3 "HelloWorld" == ["Hel","loW","orl","d"]
```

### Defining custom function, Prelude only

This function I wrote does exactly the same as chunksOf but not requiring any package to be installed:

```hs
splitInto :: Int -> String -> [String]
splitInto n = foldl (f n) [""]
    where
        f :: Int -> [String] -> Char -> [String]
        f n s x
            | (n >) $ length $ last s   = init s ++ [last s ++ [x]]
            | otherwise                 = s ++ [[x]]
```

It could probably be optimised to use `:` instead of `++` but if performance is no concern this works. Also, it could generalise for anything beyond strings.